# what is the Proper use of the play template system

Tags: java, web, playframework

Got three questions on the play Scala template system.

1. Just a clarification:
   I am assuming you create a new template for each kind of page that you want to produce - that correct?  So, a log in page, an accounts page, home page, etc?  Does this mean I should expect to have quite a few templates?
2. If I am say storing a history of orders - using java OO features with classes such as OrderLog and order.  Would it be ok to call a java method in OrderLog.java that directly creates html text that I simply pass to the Scala template or is this a bad idea?  Should I instead give the objects to the Scala engine and have that translate them?
   The two considerations I am thinking of are whether the Scala is faster at rendering the text and whether it is just bad style to have the java compose the string.
3. How do I render JSP using the play framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For good design and ease of use, you'd probably want a modular design, where repeated structures (such as a footer for instance) have their own templates. Sometimes a large portion of multiple different pages could be reused, where you should only write it down once in a template that you use on all pages (can also parametrize your template to serve two *almost similar* pages). Thus, you should create plenty of templates. Think about them as methods in your code, helps being DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid), not trying to solve all the problems in one template or forcing every page to have their own template that does practically same things as another page.
2. According to the MVC pattern, you should leave all rendering details for the views (in this case your templates) and keep it out of your models (`OrderLog`). Should be less verbose to do it in a template than trying to create HTML on server side and all your HTML is in one place, so it's clearer for new people - or yourself after a long break from working with this application.
3. You shouldn't use JSP, just the template engine. It can do everything plain JSP's would and more. Templates will be rendered when you have the server up and running and load the pages (on dev mode). You can keep changing POJO's or templates without having to republish the application or restart the server to see the differences.

Comment: Thanks - that's informative.  Just one thing - apologies I am new to Play.  Is there a way I can have code in one template and then use snippets of it from others?  Kind of like having a java super class with other classes that can extend/override methods?

Comment: Depending on the case, you can use [includes](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplateUseCases) or write your own [field constructors](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFormHelpers).